# DevOps Pipeline - Code coverage not publishing to SonarQube

Tags: .net, vb.net, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I'm integrating SonarQube into a DevOps YAML pipeline but am running into problems when publishing the results to SonarQube. The project is a collection of C# .NET Framework and VB.NET projects running on .NET Framework 4.7.2.

In the past, I've configured this for .NET Core projects using Coverlet.Collector but I'm unable to install this into the 4.7.2-based test projects as it seems it's not compatible when attempting to install the package into a 4.7.2 test project. SonarQube Enterprise, version 9.9.

> Error: The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long. C:<path>\Packages\coverlet. collector.3.2.0\build\netstandard1.0\coverlet.collector.targets

It seems this might be due to it not supporting non-SDK projects [link](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet#quick-start) which I don't believe they are, and we're unable to migrate them to be SDk-based as these projects are fairly old.

I can see the report is being published as a pipeline artefact and the pipeline task logs appear to print the coverage statistics (shown in the log output below). However, the code coverage metric when viewing the SonarQube project remains at 0.0%. All other metrics (e.g. code smells, tech debt, etc) are publishing correctly.

```
      - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
        displayName: 'Configure SonarQube'
        inputs:
          SonarQube: '<omitted>'
          scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
          projectKey: '<omitted>'
          projectName: '<omitted>'
          extraProperties: |
            sonar.exclusions=**\App_Start\*,**\*.dll,**\*.sql,**\.*.js,**\bin\**,**\*Tests,**\*.Tests*
            sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Test\Results\**\*.trx
            sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Test\Results\**\*.xml
            sonar.vbnet.vstest.reportsPaths=$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Test\Results\**\*.trx
            sonar.vbnet.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Test\Results\**\*.xml
            sonar.verbose=true

      - task: VSBuild@1
        displayName: 'Build Solution'
        inputs:
          solution: '$(solution)'
          msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
          platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

      - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'Run Test Suite'
        inputs:
          testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
          testAssemblyVer2: | 
            **\\<omitted>.dll
            **\\<omitted>.Tests.dll
            **\\<omitted>.Tests.dll
            **\\<omitted>.Tests.dll 
          searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
          resultsFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Test\Results'
          otherConsoleOptions: '/collect:"Code Coverage;Format=Cobertura" /Logger:trx'
          codeCoverageEnabled: true
      
      - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
        displayName: 'Publish Coverage Report'
        inputs:
          codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
          summaryFileLocation: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Test\Results\**\*.xml'

      - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
        displayName: 'Run SonarQube Analysis'

      - task: SonarQubePublish@5
        displayName: 'Publish SonarQube'
        inputs:
          pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

Below is the log for the publish coverage results task

```
##[warning]Multiple file or directory matches were found. Using the first match: 

D:\a\1\a\Test\Results\VssAdministrator_WIN-KJN73HDF7_2023-04-20_15_40_19\In\WIN-KJN73HDF7\VssAdministrator_WIN-KJN73HDF7_2023-04-20.15_40_08.cobertura.xml
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe D:\a\_tasks\PublishCodeCoverageResults_f0b5915b-7432-440f-a6ba-0834e2089849\1.219.0\netcoreapp2.0\ReportGenerator.dll -reports:D:\a\1\a\Test\Results\**\*.xml -targetdir:D:\a\_temp\cchtml -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      2.1.30 at [C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[warning]Failed to generate Html report. Error: 2147516566
Reading code coverage summary from 'D:\a\1\a\Test\Results\VssAdministrator_WIN-KJN73HDF7_2023-04-20_15_40_19\In\WIN-KJN73HDF7\VssAdministrator_WIN-KJN73HDF7_2023-04-20.15_40_08.cobertura.xml'
Async Command Start: Publish code coverage
Publishing coverage summary data to TFS server.
 Lines- 58062 of 122605 covered.
 Branches- 6581 of 33349 covered.
Modifying Cobertura Index file
Publishing code coverage files to TFS server.
Uploading 1 files
Max dedup parallelism: 192
Building file tree
Uploaded 0 out of 25,512,661 bytes.
Uploaded 25,512,661 out of 25,512,661 bytes.
Associating files
Total files: 1 ---- Associated files: 0 (0%)
File upload succeed.
Published 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\Code Coverage Report_603589' as artifact 'Code Coverage Report_603589'
Async Command End: Publish code coverage
Finishing: Publish Coverage Report
```

It seems to fail regarding .NET Core but then continues to read the coverage file. I've noticed a single test project is set as .NET Core 2.1 (which incidentally is not included as one of those in the `testAssemblyVer2` property) but all other projects are Framework 4.7.2.

Nearly every resource I've come across regarding coverage reports are using the `dotnet` utilities, rather than VSTest so I'm not clear where the issue is currently - the YAML, the inability to install coverlet.collector (or find a .NET Framework equivalent), or somewhere else.

### Update

I've noticed that in addition to the coverage report being generated and attached to the pipeline as an artefact, it's also visible in the Code Coverage tab on the successful pipeline run, displaying the full report breakdown. The question remains, how am I to get this over to SonarQube?